# Search Center results page quick edit functionality

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results

Im wondering if there is a way to create a page in my search center that pulls data from 10 lists (list view threshold issue having all items in one, as i am on O365) and is editable via the search results page itself and saved back to their respective lists. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for and edit list items in SharePoint Online via the search center you will have to create that yourself. The best you can do OOB is to link to the edit page for the found item.